# Overwrite an excel workbook when it is opened -VBA code

Tags: vba, excel

Is there any way to overwrite an excel file when it is opened using vba code?

Comment: Do you mean overwriting the same excel file which is executing the macro?

Comment: no no..am executing the macro from another file . I want to overwrite a file when it is opened from this macro

Comment: So why `Save` doesnt work for you?

Comment: it's not like tat. Am creating a new extract daily with the same name using this macro...So i want to overwrite the file daily. But when the file is opened, overwriting throws errors

Comment: Couple of things that you can do - 1) You can get the extract in a new workbook and then `SaveAs` with the required filename and you can specify whether to overwrite the existing file or not. 2) You can open the existing file, strip everything, dump your data and do a Save.

Comment: what if some other person has opened the file

Comment: If the file is shared and its opened by someone else, then you can't overwrite it - Windows rule. You can put a check though if its a shared workbook ... that if its open, save it with other name perhaps?

Comment: Hi..then is there any way to check if the file is opened by someone...if it is opened, then can i close it through vba?

Comment: Check [this](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=http://support.microsoft.com:80/support/kb/articles/Q138/6/21.asp&NoWebContent=1) out

Comment: hi..i tried the same...but when i closed the specific file using this code, it's showing out of range error                    Workbooks("C:\Users\extract.xlsx").Close SaveChanges:=False

Answer (score 1):

You can overwrite a file that is open in read only mode. To achieve this you need to set the file's attributes to be read only (thus forcing everyone, who's opening it to have it open in read only mode).

This can be done either within the Windows OS (change the file's properties), or through VBA using the `SetAttr` function https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/setattr.php

From my own experimentation I reached the following code, which you can use as an example. Assuming you're attempting to save a copy of the currently open workbook to `strFileLocation`, which is a string variable holding the output file's path, where the file may or may not already exist:

```
' Verify that the file exists.
If Dir(strFileLocation) <> vbNullString Then
    ' For some reason the read only flag needs to be removed for VBA to be able to overwrite the file.
    SetAttr strFileLocation, vbNormal
End If
' Do the actual (over)writing
ThisWorkbook.SaveCopyAs strFileLocation
' Set the read only flag once more
SetAttr strFileLocation, vbReadOnly
```

```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't overwrite a file that is open. This is a windows limitation and as far as I know it is not possible to do it.

So I guess you'll have to save it with a different name.

EDIT: unless you are the person that has the file open.
If you open the file via VBA code, just workbookname.save should work

Comment: Hi...then is there any way to do a check. I mean if the file is opened , then close the file...Can we do that

Comment: Do you open the file from the macro? Or is it someone else that has the file open?

Comment: i never open the exisiting file...i create a new one and overwrite the existing one...but if the exisiting one is opened by someone, i face probmelm

Comment: you can't close a file is someone else is using it. You'll have to save it as a new file. I don't know any way to notify someone using a file either.